# Using ArcPy on MacBook?

Tags: arcpy, installation, python-2.7, mac

I've done some "Googling" on this but can't quite figure it out. Is it possible to run a script that uses Arcpy on a Mac?

I have Parallels so it works for me but my co-workers do not.

Comment: You cannot install ArcGIS on a Mac (Windows only), therefore you cannot use ArcPy

Answer (score 7):

[ArcPy](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy/what-is-arcpy-.htm) is a site package bound to a release of Python associated with ArcGIS Desktop (Windows -- 32-bit or 64-bit, with Background Geoprocessing installed) or ArcGIS Server (Windows and Linux -- 64-bit).  One of these packages must be installed to `import arcpy` (and only from the version of Python installed by ArcGIS).

There is no MacOS-compatible version of arcpy without [Windows emulation technology](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/gisedcom/2007/09/05/arcgis-on-a-mac/).

If the task is compatible with ArcGIS Server operation, you may be able to submit a geoprocessing task to Server in a native Python from a MacOSX machine, but that's a far cry from native execution.

Comment: That's we finally ended up realizing but unfortunately it's $50,000 to buy ArcGIS Server so maybe in another life! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into alternatives? [Geotools](http://www.geotools.org/) has a lot of the same features as ArcMap (including reading/writing shape files). I know you're looking for a python solution, but I think there are numerous python clones (or perhaps even some sort of interface lib).

Comment: There is a really good python book for spatial data www.pygis.io. They go over the use of geopandas, rasterio, projections etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [GDAL library](http://gdal.org/) python bindings may suits you. GDAL support hundreds of [vector](http://gdal.org/ogr_formats.html) and [raster](http://gdal.org/formats_list.html) formats (ESRI shape files too).

You can get precompiled GDAL with python bindings for example from [NextGIS network installer](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/) (check the necessary software in installer interface). See blog post here: http://nextgis.com/blog/installer/

[image]